# Confusion about $-g$ in formula

Tags: kinematics, vectors, conventions, coordinate-systems

Observe a very simple case:

$$V=V_{0}+at\quad(*)$$

In $(*)$, the $+$ sign has nothing to do with direction, because it comes from:

$$a=\frac{V-V_{0}}{t-0}=\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t},$$

and the $-$ in this definition is to compute the **change**, also not about direction.

But, I've found that:

$$V_{y}=V_{0y}-gt,$$

which as a formula in some books.

And in this context **I guess** the $-$ sign is now telling me it is opposite to the direction of the assumption the author made.

Is the logic above correct?

Edit: another question:

Is there any formula of theory that the $+,-$ signs has to do with the direction?

Comment: You are correct, in $(*)$ the addition sign has nothing to do with direction, all the directional information is contained in $a$. In your second formula, someone has made a choice of coordinate axes and this means that $a = -g$, which allows you to reconcile to the two equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $v = v_o +at$ comes from the definition of a constant acceleration  $a = \dfrac{v-v_o}{t}$.

To use it you need first to **choose** a positive direction.

As an example suppose that a ball is thrown vertically upwards at $30 \;ms^{-1}$ and you are asked its velocity and position after 2 seconds with $g=10\;ms^{-2}$.

If you assume **up** as the positive direction, then

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
v_0 = +30 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}} \\
v = \; ? \\ 
a = -g = -10 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2} \\
s = \; ? \\
t = 2 \text{s}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$v = v_0+at \implies v = 30+(-10)2 = +10\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}} \ \ \ \text{(upward)}$$
$$s = \left(\frac{v+v_0}{2}\right)t \implies s = \left(\frac{30+10}{2}\right)\cdot 2 = +40 \text{m} \ \ \ \text{(upward)}$$

And if you assume **down** as the positive direction, then

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
v_0 = -30 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}} \\ 
v = \; ? \\ 
a = g = +10 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2} \\
s = \; ? \\
t = 2 \text{s}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$v = v_0+at \implies v = -30+(+10)2 = -10\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}} \ \ \ \text{(upward)}$$
$$s = \left(\frac{v+v_0}{2}\right)t \implies s = \left(\frac{-30+(-10)}{2}\right)\cdot 2 = -40\text{m} \ \ \ \text{(upward)}$$

Comment: This really helpful. But if I want to draw $V_{0}, V, g...$ in the graph, that means even the signs could be omitted, is this correct?

Comment: If you draw a graph first choose the positive direction.  In my example a graph of velocity against time will be a straight line starting from a velocity of +30 and finishing at +10 with a gradient of -10. With down as positive it would be a straight line starting from a velocity of -30 and finishing at -10 with a gradient of +10.

Comment: Just a comment regarding pedagogy: I have found it better in my teaching experience to always have $g$ as the magnitude of the gravitational field, and hence, a positive quantity. Then let $a_{\mathrm{vertical}}=-g$ if up is positive and $a_{\mathrm{vertical}}=g$ if down is positive. Plus, I never build $g$ into constant acceleration problems.  That gives students the false impression that the vertical acceleration is always $g$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the - sign here is based on a decision to define the direction of the velocity as up whereas the acceleration due to gravity is downwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose whatever sign (+ or -) for the acceleration as long as you respect it, but the equation should always be $v=v_0+at$, even when it is $v=v_0+gt$, because $g$ is already negative by convention.

Comment: No, $g$ is not negative by convention. People differ on how to use $g$. @Farcher, in another answer uses it as negative, but for others, $g$ is always a positive value, and the direction of $\vec{g}$ can be positive or negative, depending on the coordinate system one defines for a problem.